# How to build Android Studio for in app purchase?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

[Now I use PhoneGap for develop my application then I up it to Google play for Bata Testing Versions, it can purchase normally and when I run it by Android Studio, it cannot purchase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY5J0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for integration

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Here is the link for sample app

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing